# NSTableView contents not being refreshed properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I've set up an `NSTableView`, whose columns are bound to an `NSArrayController` which gets its contents from an `NSMutableArray` (`Matches`) of `NSMutableDictionary` instances.

Although the thing **is** working, I'm experiencing this issue :

When the `Matches` array is updated (and this may happen quite really often), the Table View may fail to update, but when the view is redrawn (e.g. when I minimize and reload my application) the contents appear just fine.

Any ideas on that? How could I *make* it redraw the view / update the contents?

---

**Hints :**

- I've also used `[tableView reloadData]` after updating my `Matches` array, but without effect.
- This doesn't happen ALL the time, but some times... (that is it takes some patience and clicking here-and-there or minimizing the app, before the contents show up).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're manipulating the array directly. If so, you're doing it "behind the controller's back", so to speak. It doesn't get any kind of a notification that the array has changed.

Ideally, the array controller should be the object responsible for adding and removing things from its model; you should be using `addObject:` and `removeObject:` (or similar) on the *controller*, not the array itself.

Failing that, you can issue KVO notices (`willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`) when you manipulate the array; that will make the controller pick up the changes.

Comment: Issuing KVO notices manually should be a last resort. Better is to use [KVO-compliant indexed accessor methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-SW4) to mutate the array. I'd even prefer that to messaging the controller. If you do manually emit KVO-notifications, better to use the array-specific ones `-willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:` and `-didChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:`. They allow observers to do more efficient operations in response.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It **does** work... (Baaah! I've used tables and bindings and stuff like 1000 times and I still keep missing things - although I've definitely stumbled upon them in the past; and probably fixed them as well...)